# How to compare file timestamps in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, comparison, timestamp

How do I compare the timestamp of two files?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
file1time=`stat -c %Y fil1.txt`
file2time=`stat -c %Y file2.txt`
if[$file1time -gt $file2time];
then
 doSomething
fi
```

I printed both the time stamps, in order and it gives me

```
1273143480
1254144394
./script.sh: line 13: [1273143480: command not found
```

So basically *if* comparison is not working, I guess.  Or if there is any other nice way than what I am doing, please let me know. What do I have to change?

Comment: Your code needs spaces around the square brackets.

Comment: The test mechanism is very complex compared with the built in mechanism for comparing time stamps.

Answer (score 40):

The operators for comparing time stamps are:

```
[ $file1 -nt $file2 ]
[ $file1 -ot $file2 ]
```

The mnemonic is easy: 'newer than' and 'older than'.

Answer (score 6):

This is because of some missing spaces. `[` is a command, so it must have spaces around it and the `]` is an special parameter to tell it where its comand line ends. So, your test line should look like:

```
if [ $file1time -gt $file2time ];
```

Comment: `[` is a test command -- see the "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS" section of the `bash` man page. There's also a standalone executable in `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[`, but if you're using bash and not using the full path, yo u're using the shell builtin.

Comment: @Doug Harris +1 for the more complete explanation about the topic.

Answer (score 2):

`if` is not magic. It attempts to run the command passed to it, and checks if it has a zero exit status. It also doesn't handle non-existent arguments well, which is why you should quote variables being used in it.

```
if [ "$file1time" -gt "$file2time" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( [ $file1time -gt $file2time ] );
then
 doSomething
fi
```

Comment: The parentheses are superfluous.  They force the test to be run in a subshell.  The square brackets with space around them are sufficient.